# How can I calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty}((x^3-x^2+\frac{x}{2})e^{\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{x^6+1})$?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

> Given:
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty}((x^3-x^2+\frac{x}{2})e^{\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{x^6+1})$$

How can I calculate this limit? I tried to calculate the limit by use of Taylor for $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ but I don't have idea how to calculate it.

Comment: You close to right solution. Just write Taylor series like $e^{1/x} = 1 + \frac{1}{x} + o(\frac{1}{x})$ And then simplify $\sqrt{x^{6}+1} = x^{3}\sqrt{1+x^{-6}}$ (you can use Taylor series for this).

Comment: $e^{1/x}=1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{1}{6x^3}+...$ and $\sqrt{x^6+1}$ is approx $x^3$. A little FOIL might help to. Lots is going to cancel

Comment: @imranfat : I was not aware of the term FOIL. Thanks!!

Comment: Please stay clear of using preformated question templates:  "Given [fill in current formula I want an answer for].  How can I calculate this limit?  I tried to calculate the limit by use of Taylor for [to be filled in, per limit I want an answer to], but I don't have idea how to calculate it."  Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615517/how-can-i-calculate-lim-x-to-inftyx-frac32-sqrtx1-sqrtx-1, e.g.

Comment: @amWhy : will take care of this template and its variations in future. And the pending close vote now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Factor out $x^6$ in both terms  to obtain a second factor in $u=\dfrac1x$, and expand $\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{x^6}}$ with the first terms of the binomial series.

Answer (score 0):

> *I tried to calculate the limit by use of Taylor for $e^{\frac1x}$ but I don't have idea how to calculate it.*

**Hint.** 
If one knows that, as $u \to 0$,
$$
e^u=1+u+\frac {u^2}2+\frac{u^3}6+O(u^4)
$$ then, as $x \to \infty$, one gets
$$
e^{\large\frac1x}=1+\frac1x+\frac 1{2x^2}+\frac 1{6x^3}+O\left(\frac1{x^4} \right).
$$ By multiplying
$$
\left(x^3-x^2+\frac{x}{2}\right)e^{\large\frac{1}{x}}
$$ one obtains a polynomial in terms of $\frac 1x$.

Similarly, as $x \to \infty$, by using a taylor expansion, one has
$$
\sqrt{x^6+1}=x^3\cdot \sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^6}}=x^3\cdot\left(1+\frac 1{2x^6}+ O\left(\frac1{x^{12}} \right)\right)
$$ which might help to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

We have, using the fact that $1/x\to 0$ when $x\to \infty$,
$$
e^{1/x} = 1+ \frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{2x^2}+ \frac{1}{6x^3} + o\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)
$$
when $x\to \infty$. This will help you deal with the term $e^{1/x}$.

Similarly, to deal with the $\sqrt{x^6+1}$, we can factor and use the same trick:
$$
\sqrt{x^6+1} = x^3\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^6}} = x^3\left(1+\frac{1}{2x^6}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)\right) = x^3+o(1)
$$
when $x\to\infty$.

---

Now,
$$\begin{align}
\left(x^3-x^2+\frac{x}{2}\right)e^{\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{x^6+1}
&= 
\left(x^3-x^2+\frac{x}{2}\right)e^{\frac{1}{x}}-x^3\sqrt{1+1/x^6}\\
&= 
\left(x^3-x^2+\frac{x}{2}\right)e^{\frac{1}{x}}-x^3\left(1+\frac{1}{2x^6}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^6}\right)\right)\\
&= 
\left(x^3-x^2+\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{2x^2}+ \frac{1}{6x^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)-\left(x^3+o(1)\right)\\
&= 
\left(x^3-x^2+\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{2x^2}+ \frac{1}{6x^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)-\left(x^3+o(1)\right)\\
&=\left(x^3 +x^2 + \frac{x}{2}+ \frac{1}{6}+o(1)\right)-\left(x^2+x+\frac{1}{2}+o(1)\right)+\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+o(1)\right)-(x^3+o(1))\\
&=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+o(1)) = \frac{1}{6}+o(1)\\
&\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \boxed{\frac{1}{6}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: How you know which order to take for any function when you use by taylor?

Comment: @J.Roe Two options: trial and error, or guessing and intuition. The first factor's dominating term is $x^3$, so going to $o(1/x^3)$ for the exponential makes sense: we want the limit, so once we get to $x^3\cdot o(1/x^3) = o(1)$ we are done. Similarly for the $\sqrt{x^6+1}$: once we have $o(1)$, we are good as far as limits are concerned.

Comment: but if for example i will take other order I can get that the limit is $0$ or $\infty$ - How can i knew that it's error?

Comment: @J.Roe You *need* to go to that order to get to the $o(1)$, in this case. Since $x^3$ is multplied by $e^{1/x}$, and you need that to go to order $o(1)$. And there is no reason to go to a higher (further) order, since you only care about the limit, so going beyond $o(1)$ is wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=1/t$ so that $t\to 0^{+}$ and the expression under limit is transformed into $$\frac{(1-t+t^2/2)e^{t}-\sqrt{1+t^6}} {t^3} $$ Multiplying numerator and denominator by $(1-t+t^2/2)e^t+\sqrt{1+t^6}$ and noting that this factor tends to $2$ we can see that the desired limit is equal to the limit of the expression $$\frac {(1-t+t^2/2)^2e^{2t}-1-t^6}{2t^3}$$ which is same as the limit of $$\frac{(1-t+t^2/2)^2e^{2t}-1}{2t^3}$$ which is same as that of $$\frac{(1-t+t^2/2)^2-e^{-2t}}{2t^3}$$ Factoring the numerator via $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b) $ and noting that $a+b\to 2$ it is easy to see that the desired limit is equal to the limit of $$\frac{1-t+t^2/2-e^{-t}}{t^3}$$ Now the Taylor series for $e^{-t} $ gives the answer $1/6$ immediately. I always avoid multiplication, division and composition of Taylor series unless absolutely necessary. That way the problem of figuring out the number of terms needed in the Taylor series is trivialized.